Excel returns #VALUE! error when I use INDIRECT
I'm new to Excel and I'm writing an Excel formula that counts the employees state across the entire year( for example: how many times he had a vacation donated as letter V)
and I managed to write this formula
 =SUMPRODUCT( COUNTIFS( INDIRECT("'" & {"JAN", "FEB", "MAR", "APR", "MAY", "JUN", "JUL", "AUG", "SEP", "OCT", "NOV", "DEC"} & "'!$A$11:$A$38"), $B2, INDIRECT("'" & {"JAN", "FEB", "MAR", "APR", "MAY", "JUN", "JUL", "AUG", "SEP", "OCT", "NOV", "DEC"} & "'!$B$11:$AF$38"), "V" ) )

and in the employees sheet it start with id then the name and then an empty cell for the state(as shown in the sample table below)



ID
Name
Vacation




1
Adam
0



in this code I'm looking for the state of V (Vacation) for the first employee located in cell B2.
I have 12 worksheets for months. Each sheet is similar to the other in terms of the location of employees' names and the cells for the state of the day.
In each month's sheet, the names go from A11 to A38.
And the area for the states is from B11 to AF38( in this square).a sample table is below



ID
Name
Day-1




1
Adam
0


2
John
0



In the employees statistics sheet from A2 to A23 is for  the IDs.
And from B2 to B23 is for the names.
And from C2 to V24 is the area for each state each employee taking a row of course
I added a name tag ( or whatever it's called) from the names manager. to use them in the formula as you can see. but when ever i use the formula it says in the cell #VALUE!. I've tried to evaluate the formula and see where is the bug but I just couldn't see where the issue is. the furthers i managed to come is to tell that the issue is around (INDIRECT) function,but i don't know how to solve it.

There are lots of problems in your formula.
First, you just can't put two criteria ranges with different dimension in COUNTIFS. that is, name range is A11:A38 (1-D array), but state range is
B11:AF38 (2-D array). the two ranges have different shapes, and that won't work in COUNTIFS.
Second, INDIRECT doesn't work with arrays such as {"JAN!A11:A38", FEB!A11:A38"}.
I believe what you need is 3D reference instead: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-a-3-d-reference-to-the-same-cell-range-on-multiple-worksheets-40ca91ff-9dcb-4ad1-99d2-787d0bc888b6
I hope you have Office365.
Because with Office365, you can use 3D reference together with VSTACK to consolidate your 12 month's data into one table:
=VSTACK(JAN:FEB!A11:C13)

Then you can use below to count vacations for "John":
=SUM(--(FILTER(B2:C7,A2:A7="John","")="V")).
=FILTER(B2:C7,A2:A7="John","") filters out data for "John".
=SUM(--(FILTER(B2:C7)="V") count the number of state = "V".
Edited:
For easier implementation, you can put =VSTACK(JAN:FEB!$A$11:$C$38) in name manager. (I named it "Consolidated"). (Make sure you use absolute reference. i.e do not omit the dollar sign).

To get all employee names in 12months data, use =TAKE(Consolidated,,1). To get all the states column in 12months data, use =DROP(Consolidated,,1).
So to filter out data for an employee, use =FILTER(DROP(Consolidated,,1),TAKE(Consolidated,,1)=B2,"")


could you tell me in detail how to use this formula and what each parameter means so I can incorporate it into my tables

You have no problems using=VSTACK(JAN:DEC!A11:AF38) to consolidate data in different sheets? you just need explanation on FILTER()? @ZiadBarnawi

I just want to know what I need to write to get a general formula that works for every employee in the employee sheet. From what I just read, VSTACK would return the 12-month sheets one below the other. but I don't know how to write the condition in the (include) part of the filter. because the condition is that it matches the employees name and has the work state in the same row and the employee's name. and I don't know how to know the length of the 12  arrays one above the other to put it in the condition dynamically

=LET(stacked,VSTACK(JAN:FEB!A11:C38),names,TAKE(stacked,,1),states,DROP(stacked,,1),included,names=B2,filtered,FILTER(states,included,""),SUM(--(filtered="V"))).  You can use =TAKE(stacked,,1) to get the first column (the name column) in VSTACK. =DROP(stacked,,1) to get the states columns in VSTACK.  your "included" condition would be TAKE(stacked,,1)=B2

ok, this formula is working for every employee except the last one it says 12 on every cell for his states even though they should be 0. Any idea why that is the case?

What does =LET(stacked,VSTACK(JAN:FEB!A11:C38),names,TAKE(stacked,,1),states,DROP(stacked,,1),included,names=B23,filtered,FILTER(states,included,""),filtered) return? (this returns the filtered rows for employee B23)

There was just an error in the ranges you wrote. I fixed it and now it's working. thanks for the help
